# Responsive viewport switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I'm building a site using the Bootstrap framework. I've found two excellent bits of functionality that I have added - the only thing is it would be great i they could work together.

1) Viewport button - this gives the user an option to see desktop version when on tablet and vice versa - this came from http://responsiveviewport.com/

2) A toggle switch - this turns an input boxes into a on/off switch or whatever switch you want - http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

I've had a go at combining the two but my Jquery skills are still more towards amateur level.
The issue I had was that the responsive button is a `a href` and not an input field I think the input needs to accept the URL to redirect to the page or refresh.

Can this be done? Would be a great little bit of functionality for all to use.

The below link is the viewport button:

```
            <a class='reView pull-left visible-xs visible-sm navbar-toggle' data-defaultText='Mobile View' data-coreText='Desktop View' href='index.html'>Desktop View</a>
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about why they don't work together, and what happens (e.g. error messages) when you try to use them together? You're also talking about `a` tags without context (I don't see `a` being used by bootstrap-switch anywhere), so where did that come from? What do you mean by "input needs to accept the URL"? Where did redirecting or refreshing the page come from, since it doesn't seem to have to do with your problem?

Comment: Thanks for reading Zhihao. The responsive viewport button has been added to my above question. When it is clicked is activates the "turn off" and refreshes/reloads the page. Nothing happens when I tried adding them. So, in order for the switch to "refresh" i need it to accept the URL when activated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want a toggle switch that says Mobile view | Desktop view? If so could you attach the setMobile()/setDefault() functions ([Docs - scroll down to Extensions](http://responsiveviewport.com/?c=docs)) of reView to the [event handler of Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#event-handler-javascript).

Big flashing neon sign here to say that this is not working code, just some semi-pseudo code (is that a thing?)

```
$('#switch-change').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
  //interrogate the switch to work out what position it has been switched to
  //if mobile
  reView.setMobile();
});
```

From what I understand from the docs, you should be able to use that to change the page to 'Mobile' view on the change event of the switch, without having to use `<a>`.

It does mean you will likely have to implement your own handling code on load to set the switch to the right position in the first place (likely using `reView.mode;`)

That's an educated guess anyway, I have not used either of these before (although I rather like the looks of Bootstrap Switch, so cheers for that).